# How to get no. of days between 2 dates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a beginner learning SQL. My code may be rough.  I have 2 tables. Trying to get the no. of days since account opened for each row in transaction table. Code I'm using keeps giving me an error.

Table1: `Orders`

```
Customer_Id  TxnDate     Amount
-------------------------------
4001         21-Aug-18   245.99
4002         30-Jan-18    49.99
4003         15-Apr-17   204.87
4001         18-Dec-18   130.88
4004         15-May-17   198.33
4006          4-Feb-17   783.65
```

Table2: `Customers`

```
    Customer_Id  AcctOpenDate  CustomerFirstName  CustomerLastName
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    4001          7-Jan-16     John               Doe
    4002         15-Apr-15     Ashley             Smith
    4003         14-May-14     Carter             Jones
    4004         17-Sep-16     Ika                Gaut
    4005         18-Aug-14     Gray               Show
    4006         25-Oct-15     Kathia             Kim
```

Query:

```
SELECT c.Customer_Id, c.AcctOpenDate, c.CustomerFirstName, c.CustomerLastName 
FROM dbo.Customers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders ON Orders.Customer_Id = Customers.Customer_Id; 

SELECT DATEDIFF (d, "AcctOpenDate", "TxnDate") AS Dayssinceacctopen 
FROM dbo.Orders;
```

Current error produced:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
>   Invalid object name 'dbo.Customers'

Comment: It says that there is no table with name Customers in the database. Either you are running query against a wrong database or you actually don't have the table in the database.

Comment: That is why this is so confusing.  The 2nd table is the Customers table.

Comment: Perhaps its not plural, or not dbo? This will confirm it: `select * from information_schema.tables where table_name like '%cust%'`

Comment: Are you expecting just one combined result set by the way? You have two separate queries.

Comment: Can you add your expected output of your query considering those 2 input tables?

Comment: I would like an additional column titled Dayssinceacctopen appended to table as one combined result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed in the comment that you need an additional column titled Dayssinceacctopen appended to table order, I think you can use INNER JOIN between table order and customer to get the desired result set as below-

```
SELECT 
C.Customer_Id, 
C.AcctOpenDate, 
C.CustomerFirstName, 
C.CustomerLastName,
O.TxnDate,
O.Amount,
DATEDIFF(DD,C.AcctOpenDate,O.TxnDate) Dayssinceacctopen
FROM Orders O
INNER JOIN Customers C ON O.Customer_Id = C.Customer_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the difference between those two dates you could use this query :

```
SELECT c.Customer_Id, c.AcctOpenDate, c.CustomerFirstName, c.CustomerLastName,
       DATEDIFF(day, c.AcctOpenDate, o.TxnDate) AS DaysSinceAcctOpen 
FROM Customers c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders o ON o.Customer_Id = c.Customer_Id;
```

I have set an alias for the Customers table, because you were using that "c" alias on the result field names.

Does this query still raise the same error of invalid object name Customers?